# Regex function in a loop runs slowly

Tags: python-3.x, regex, loops, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to apply 15 regular expressions to a Spark DataFrame.
I will add version with small `df` and 3 regexps here:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  Row(a=1, val1="aaa_wwwwwww"),
  Row(a=2, val1="bwq_323"),
  Row(a=3, val1="haha_kdjk_ska")
])

reg_exps = [
  {"reg_val": "^aaa_[a-z]{5,12}$", "replace_with": "a"},
  {"reg_val": "^bwq_[0-9]{2,4}$", "replace_with": "b"},
  {"reg_val": "^haha_[0-9a-z_]{5,12}$", "replace_with": "c"},
]
for reg_exp in reg_exps:
  df = df.withColumn(
    "val1",
    when(
        col("val1").rlike(reg_exp["reg_val"]), 
        lit(reg_exp["replace_with"])
    ).otherwise(col("val1"))
)

df.show(truncate=False)
```

It should return following dataframe:

```
+---+----+
|a  |val1|
+---+----+
|1  |a   |
|2  |b   |
|3  |c   |
+---+----+
```

The code works as expected but it's really slow. Is there any ways of speeding it up?

Comment: Thanks for providing the code to reproduce the input! This is suuuuper helpful!

Comment: You don't want to parse the cells that you already replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Attempt 1**

From what can be seen, you can create just one [**`regexp_extract`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract), without a loop.

For a. b. c:

```
df = df.withColumn("val1", regexp_extract("val1", r"^([a-c])_[\da-z]{5,12}$", 1))
```

For any letter that is in that position:

```
df = df.withColumn("val1", regexp_extract("val1", r"^([a-z])_[\da-z]{5,12}$", 1))
```

**Attempt 2**

Since you said, in your real case, you cannot merge your regexes, there's one thing you can simplify without it. Instead of several `.withColumn`, you can do just one. You would need to combine your `.when()` conditions into one: `F.when().when().when().w....otherwise()`. This can be done using `reduce`. With such form, I think, values which already got a regex match, would not experience several additional regex checks.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from functools import reduce

whens = reduce(
    lambda acc, x: acc.when(F.col("val1").rlike(x["reg_val"]), x["replace_with"]),
    reg_exps,
    F
).otherwise(F.col("val1"))

df = df.withColumn("val1", whens)
```